# What is the difference between 仏 and 釈迦？

Tags: words, names, religion

Both 仏 and 釈迦 are defined as "Buddha" in my dictionary. Is there a difference between these words?

Comment: The answer to this question appears to greatly depend on which sect of Buddhism one subscribes to (http://timeisbunny.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/03/27/213750). Do you want an answer about *common* usage or technical usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

仏 **basically** means (lowercase) buddha, that is, past participle of a verb that means to wake in Sanskrit or one who are awaken, not limited to Gautama Buddha. 釈迦 refers to Gautama Siddhartha himself.